# How to hide/unhide toolbar onCameraChange in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have my own toolbar defined on my googlemap. Like uber have done, i want to hide toolbar oncamerachange and show the toolbar when i take back my hand. Please help me to it

```
     @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

This is my logic. Is there is any other method to implement this idea.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is supported by [Android Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar). You may need to:

1. Set UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean) to true or false to enable/disable the toolbar.
2. Use useGoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener. It is called after the camera position has changed

Examples [codes here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener).